# Google sheets .getvalues gives no values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

When I run the following script, it gives no data, does anybody knows why?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetInput = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard_Data");
var lastrow = sheetInput.getRange(3, 43).getLastRow();
var wsInput = sheetInput.getRange(3, 43, lastrow, 6).getValues;
```

It should extract the values from this excel sheet.

[image: example]

Comment: to execute a function in any programming language you need to add parentheses at the end of the function, otherwise you get a reference of that function. In other words, replace `getValues` with `getValues()`. You can see this pattern in `getActiveSpreadsheet()`, `getSheetByName("Dashboard_Data")` and `getLastRow()`. Why did you add parentheses there and not in `getValues` ?

Comment: Thx, I knew it was something really simple. This piece of code was a snippet of a large part. So I just couldn't see that I forgot to at the () haha